# Set MUI Collapse component to "collapsed" by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm making a React/Next/MUI project, and I wonder how i could set the **MUI Collapse** element to collapsed by default instead of having it opened (which could be horrible for large navigations). Here's the code :

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
const handleClick = () => {
      setOpen(!open);
    };
```

```
<ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
 <ListItemText primary="Menu"/>
</ListItem>
    
<Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
 <List component="div" disablePadding>
  <ListItem button>
   <ListItemIcon>
    </ListItemIcon>
     <ListItemText primary="Whatever" />
  </ListItem>
 </List>
</Collapse>
```

It might be something quite simple, but I'm not familiar with MUI API... If you need further details, let me know !
Thanks for the help and the great community !

Comment: This code seems fine. I just copied your code here ( https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4c4y5?file=/demo.js:1062-1073) and it's working. Can you share more detail about your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `<Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>` setting `open` to `true` which by default open the `Collapse` component. So set `open` to `false`

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
```